# Amazon products API for Amazon Instant Video

Tags: php, api, amazon-ecs, amazon-product-api

With Amazon products API, I want to get first products found in categories "DVD" and "Amazon Instant Video" with keyword "my movie".

Thanks to https://github.com/Exeu/Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library it works for DVD :

```
$amazonEcs = new AmazonECS(AWS_API_KEY, AWS_API_SECRET_KEY, 'com', AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG);
$amazonEcs->associateTag(AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG);
$amazonEcs->returnType(AmazonECS::RETURN_TYPE_ARRAY);
$response = $amazonEcs->responseGroup('Small')->category('DVD')->search('my movie');
```

But I can't find what category I have to use to get VOD...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to do what I want. There is no category for VOD, you have to use [nodeid](http://www.browsenodes.com/) as second parameter of `search` (but you still have to provide a category first) :

```
$amazonEcs = new AmazonECS(AWS_API_KEY, AWS_API_SECRET_KEY, 'com', AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG);
$amazonEcs->associateTag(AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG);
$amazonEcs->returnType(AmazonECS::RETURN_TYPE_ARRAY);
$response = $amazonEcs->category('DVD')->responseGroup('Large')->search('my movie', 2858905011);
```